# SQL Exception: Transport-Level error occurred

Tags: c#, sql, sqlexception

We are developing a network-based multi-user application. There are some clients running on the same database (in average 4-5 PCs using the same Database). We are recently facing recurring Exceptions only on one machine with the following message:

An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 0 - The data is invalid.)

`System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 0 - The data is invalid.)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery1.GetResults(Nullable1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
   at Repositories.DeviceRepository.DoSomething(IEnumerable1 detectedDevices) in c:\Path\To\Project\DeviceRepository.cs:line 66
[...]`

I assume it has to be a problem on this specific machine (running Windows 7 x64), but i have no clue what could be the reason. All the other clients are running 100% stable, showing no exceptions over a long period run.

What can cause this specific error (regarding error code 0 - i found several other threads but none with error code 0 for session provider)?

Comment: Which operating system are the other clients using? And is your SQL client up-to-date?

Comment: Has this client machine ever worked i.e. has the error suddently started coming or it is coming since the application has been installed. also can u check if the domain of non working and working client are same or different?

Comment: We all are using the very same OS as they are installed by our system administrator. He told me that all machines are configured in the same way using the same updates. We do not need to install a SQL client as we're using the build-in .net SQL Client. Some of the clients are development machines having installed development tools (VS, SQL Server 2008 R2...), but this specific machine is a "normal" PC without any development tools.

Comment: All machines are running in the same domain. The application started showing this bug since beginning, but the bug is showing randomly after 30min - 2 hours (what is strange, because this specific method is triggered every 10 seconds).

Comment: Try to use some utilities from Microsoft to check network issues in db connections. 1 of the tool is http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328101 which u can try. It is safe to use as it is given by Microsoft only. In past I had a similar problem related to running distributed transactions from .net code. 1 of the utility from Microsoft helped me to identify a specific port was blocked by firewall which was resulting in the failure.